# in objective c, why or how can parameters be placed at the front

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm looking at a message like the following in the UITableViewDataSource protocol:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

and have never fully understood why the tableView part is at the beginning (is this the name of message or is it a param). It seems like it should be:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section 
                      withTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
```

What does the  tableView:(UITableView *)tableView represent? It is listed as a parameter but it seems like it should at the end? What am I missing here? How should it even be read?

thx for any help

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2012/05/24/api-design/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Objective-C method names are a little bit different than in most languages, in that the parameters to the method are often part of the method name.

You read that method name as "tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:". It takes two arguments referred to as "section" and "tableView" in the method body.

Whether the table view object is listed first or last is really a matter of style, but since it's the "subject" of this message, it makes some sense to list it first; Objective-C style emphasizes readability, so this method can almost read like a sentence: "The table view has *x* number of rows in the given section."

Comment: thx mipadi hmmm... it still seems really odd. Is table view really just a param? I had previously tried to move the tableView to the end and it crashed (no surprise; different signatures). So whether the params are before or after is dependent upon the signature.

Comment: @timpone: Which `tableView`? One `tableView` is part of the method signature, and another one is the name for an argument.

Comment: I moved both of them - not a surprise as different sig. Is this a delegation thing? Just curious - already accepted answer.

Comment: @timpone: Is the choice of ordering a delegation thing? I suppose so, as delegate methods often follow this pattern, but it's really just a choice. (As for moving it around -- no, you can't do that, but I don't know of any language in which you can call a function with the parameters in the wrong order and have it still work.)

Comment: Yes, it is a style of method name common for delegation. It makes a little bit more sense sometimes when the method is named something like `someClass:didDoSomethingWithSomething:`. In this case it means, "Dear delegate, I, the someClass, did do something with something."

Answer (score 2):

In Objective-C, method names are interleaved with the arguments. So this:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section;
```

and this:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section withTableView:(UITableView *)tableView;
```

are equivalent in the sense that either would could be used to accomplish the same end goal, they are not interchangeable. The name of the first method (ie. the message sent to invoke it) is `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:`, while the second is `numberOfRowsInSection:withTableView:`. As mipadi mentioned, Objective-C methods should generally be readable almost as regular English. If you called the method `numberOfRowsInSection:ofTableView:`, I would argue that that's a good name. For whatever reason, that's not the convention that the people who designed the APIs in the first place chose.

The reason for having the tableView argument at all is so that you can determine *which* tableView is being asked about, in case you have multiple tableViews which all have the same dataSource object.

In this specific case, I believe the reason for the tableView being the first argument is to make it more closely match NSTableView's API on OS X, along with other delegate methods in Cocoa, which *long* predate iOS and UITableView. Why the decision was made to have tableView come first in NSTableView's API, is lost to history, but again, that's the way Apple (actually NeXT) designed it.

Comment: thx Andrew. parts of it seem very counterintuitive but all languages have quirks. thx again

Answer (score 1):

Putting the source of the call at the beginning is a common pattern with delegate methods.  It's important to have this parameter because a single object could be the delegate (or in this case data source) for more than one view, and it will need that parameter to know which delegate method calls are being made on behalf go which view. Whether it's first or last is largely arbitrary and has no technical significance.

Comment: ok. thx, so it might signify delegation. It's just so strange that most of the iOS books just gloss over this the first time; I still think it's incredibly odd. Makes ruby look very standard ;-)